For loop to set Interior.ColorIndex unless cell is blank
I want to color in the cells of a range based on whether the projected date (col "X") is before, equal to, or after the actual date (col "Y").
It worked until I tried to introduce the default, which is NO interior color and the text "not complete".
Sub ColorChangeTATDates()

Dim lr As Long
lr = Sheet1.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim i As Long, projected As Range, actual As Range
For i = 3 To lr
  Set projected = Range("X" & i)
  Set actual = Range("Y" & i)
  If actual.Value = " " Then actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 And actual.Cells.Value = "not complete"
  If actual.Value < projected.Value Then actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
  If actual.Value >= projected.Value Then actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
  Debug.Print (projected.Value)
  Debug.Print (actual.Value)
Next i

End Sub

What happens:

All empty cells turn blue.
"not complete" does not print to empty cells.

I need to modify my loop to set the "Y" range cell value to "not complete" and no fill (which I feel like I shouldn't have to specify) until certain criteria is met.

This line:
 If actual.Value = " " Then actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 And actual.Cells.Value = "not complete"

Is actually read like:
If actual.Value = " " Then actual.Interior.ColorIndex = (0 And actual.Cells.Value = "not complete")

Which rectifies to something like
If actual.Value = " " Then actual.Interior.ColorIndex = (FALSE And FALSE)

The reason this is happening is because And compares two conditions, so it treats both 0 and actual.Cells.Value = "not complete" as a condition. 0 is exactly equal to the boolean value False and actual.Cells.Value = "not complete" at this point in the execution will also be False. So really you are just setting the interior.colorindex property to False And False which is False which is just 0.
At any rate, you want to run two lines of code when that if condition is true, so you'll need to use an if block instead of a one-liner:
If actual.Value = " " Then 
   actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 
   actual.Cells.Value = "not complete"
End If

You may also want to check on that If actual.Value = " " Then line since " " is a literal space character. An empty cell would be ""
Full Code:
Sub ColorChangeTATDates()

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Sheet1.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
    Dim i As Long, projected As Range, actual As Range
    
    For i = 3 To lr
        Set projected = Range("X" & i)
        Set actual = Range("Y" & i)
        
        If actual.Value = " " Then
            actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            actual.Cells.Value = "not complete"
        End If
        
        If actual.Value < projected.Value Then actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        If actual.Value >= projected.Value Then actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        
        Debug.Print (projected.Value)
        Debug.Print (actual.Value)
    Next i
End Sub


Now I am getting an error for the Next i. "Next without For"...
I have the "End If" then "Next i", then "End Sub"

Just a sec. I'll update the answer with the full code (which should work, I think)

Ah, I had the End If in the wrong spot and it does work now! The "not complete" cells turn green, but I think if I add another condition
If actual.Value < projected.Value AND actual.Value <> "not completed" Then...


The problem I kept running into with my previous code is that it would fill the internal color of the "not complete" cells with green.
Instead of continuing to qualify a cell as = "" (blank) or <> "" (not blank), I went with the boolean IsDate. Now it doesn't matter what's in the column, if it's not a date it won't get colored in.
This also negated the need to define another qualification. If the cell is not a date, and isn't <= the projected date column, then it's green.
I'm sure there's some redundancy in this code, but it works! And I know there will never be more than 20 rows of data for it to go through, so I don't have to worry about runtime.
Sub ColorChangeTATDates()

    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Sheet1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
    Dim i As Long, projected As Range, actual As Range
    
    For i = 3 To LR
        Set projected = Range("X" & i)
        Set actual = Range("Y" & i)
        If IsDate(Range("Y" & i)) = False Then
         actual.Cells.Value = "not complete"
        ElseIf IsDate(Range("Y" & i)) = True And _
        actual.Value <= projected.Value Then
        actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        Else
        actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

